# CKEDITOR is not working with promise call back

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, ckeditor

```
     employer_data = functionToGetEmployer();
     $.when(fillData()).then(
      function(status){
        console.log("reaching here");
        if(employer_data.detailsMessage !== null){
         console.log("reaching here too");
CKEDITOR.instances.employer_detail_message.setData(employer_data.detailsMessage);
        }
      }
    )

    fillData: function(){
      var dfd = jQuery.Deferred();

      $.ajax({
        // some ajax call to get some data.

        success: function(){
          // do something
          dfd.resolve("resolved");
        },
        error: function(){
          dfd.reject("rejected");
        }

      })
       return dfd.promise();
    }
```

In the above the ckeditor setData method is not working.

If I keep the setData method above the promise setup then it works as expected.

Comment: missing quote `dfd.reject("rejected);`

Comment: `fillData: function(){` - looks like `fillData` is a method of some object ... yet you call it like `fillData()` I would've expected code along the lines of `someObject.fillData()`... have you checked the browser **developer** tools console for errors?

Comment: Yes this jquery code is related to one object only. the typo/way the data is being fetched that's correct. It's just with the setData it does not work. instead of promise I just keep the CKEDITOR.setData in the success section then it works as expected.

Comment: so, no errors in the developer tools console at all

Comment: Nope. no errors.

Comment: Why are you using `employer_data` when `filldata()` resolves? What does the resolve of `filldata()` have to do with the `employer_data`?

Comment: @Ajay, doesn't make sense. There's got to be something you're not telling us.

Comment: Employer data should be filled from the response from ajax, not from other function like functionToGetEmployer(), that doesn't make sense. Ajax returns a promise, no need for filldata(). Use something like this: `var ajaxCall = $.ajax({...});` to get the employer data and then `ajaxCall.done(function(data) {...});` to use `setData()` for CKEditor.